# Why are my ValidationErrors not rendering anymore?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a form that has to check a few things before submission to make sure the data is valid. Before I did a few changes (went from class based views to function based) everything worked fine, but when I went back to test everything I noticed that a very important part was not working properly, which is the number validation.

What used to happen before was that, if a number that was not in the DB was entered, the user would be shown an error at the top. If they entered a number that was in the DB, but it was not the right "team" then it would show an error. I was handling this in forms.py, and completely forgot about this since it was working before, and all the things I started working with were in views.py. Now, while it will not actually submit the form (so it is still going through the logic) it will not display any errors. It will just re-render the page but empty, and not submit anything unless the data entered is right. The logic that would handle this was clean_employee_number.

I'm not sure If I deleted something from my html without noticing, but I have been trying to figure out what could have cause this to stop working and I cannot figure it out. I am also not sure if it could have been due to the widget, since I made that change afterwards (it is a widget because the employee_number is tied to the "id" of the employee which is stored in another model called Salesman).

**models.py**

```
class EmployeeWorkAreaLog(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeleteModel, models.Model):
    employee_number = models.ForeignKey(Salesman, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, help_text="Employee #", null=True, blank=False)
    work_area = models.ForeignKey(WorkArea, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False, help_text="Work Area", related_name="work_area")
    station_number = models.ForeignKey(Station, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, help_text="Station", related_name="stations", blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class WarehouseForm(AppsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
        widgets = {
            'employee_number': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(EmployeeWorkAreaLog._meta.get_field('employee_number').remote_field, site, attrs={'id':'employee_number_field'}),
        }
        fields = ('employee_number', 'work_area', 'station_number', 'edited_timestamp')

    def clean_employee_number(self):
        employee_number = self.cleaned_data.get('employee_number')

        if employee_number is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Must enter emp #")
        elif employee_number.team is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Not valid")
        elif employee_number.team not in ('WF', 'WP', 'OM') or employee_number.employee_status not in 'A':
            raise forms.ValidationError("Employee not valid, please contact manager")
```

**views.py**

```
def enter_exit_area(request):
    form = WarehouseForm(request.POST or None)
    enter_without_exit = None
    exit_without_enter = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        temp = request.POST.copy()
        form = WarehouseForm(temp)
        if form.is_valid():
            emp_num = form.cleaned_data['employee_number']
            area = form.cleaned_data['work_area']
            station = form.cleaned_data['station_number']
            edited_time = form.cleaned_data['edited_timestamp']

            if 'enter_area' in request.POST:
                new_entry = form.save()
                EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter((Q(employee_number=emp_num) & Q(work_area=area) & Q(time_out__isnull=True) & Q(time_in__isnull=True)) & (Q(station_number=station) | Q(station_number__isnull=True))).update(time_in=datetime.now())

                # If employee has an entry without an exit and attempts to enter a new area, mark as an exception 'N'
                enters_without_exits = EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter(Q(employee_number=emp_num) & Q(time_out__isnull=True) & Q(time_exceptions="")).exclude(pk=new_entry.pk).order_by("-time_in")
                if len(enters_without_exits) > 0:
                    enter_without_exit = enters_without_exits[0]
                    enters_without_exits.update(time_exceptions='N')

                message = 'You have entered %(area)s' % {'area': area}
                if station is not None:
                    message += ': %(station)s' % {'station': station}
                messages.success(request, message)

            elif 'leave_area' in request.POST:
                # Something similar to above

    form = WarehouseForm()
    return render(request, "operations/enter_exit_area.html", {
        'form': form,
        'enter_without_exit': enter_without_exit,
        'exit_without_enter': exit_without_enter,
    })
```

**enter_exit_area.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block main %}
    <form id="warehouseForm" action="" method="POST" novalidate >
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        {{ form.source.errors }}
        {{ form.source }}

        <div>
            <div>
                <div>{{ form.employee_number.errors.as_text }}</div>
                <label>Employee #</label>
                {{ form.employee_number }}
            </div>

            <div>
                <div>{{ form.work_area.errors.as_text }}</div>
                <label>Work Area</label>
                {{ form.work_area }}
            </div>
            <div>{{ form.station_number.errors.as_text }}</div>
            <div>
                <label>Station</label>
                {{ form.station_number }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="enter_area" value="Enter">Enter Area</button>
                <button type="submit" name="leave_area" value="Leave">Leave Area</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: You construct a *new* form if the input is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You construct a *new* form in case it is a POST request and the form is not valid. The workflow of your `enter_exit_area` should be:

```
def enter_exit_area(request):
    enter_without_exit = None
    exit_without_enter = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WarehouseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # …
            return redirect('some-view')
    else:
        form = WarehouseForm()
    return render(request, "operations/enter_exit_area.html", {
        'form': form,
        'enter_without_exit': enter_without_exit,
        'exit_without_enter': exit_without_enter,
    })
```

Notice thus that the `form = WarehouseForm()` is constructed in an *`else`* block of the `if request.method == 'POST'`.

In case of a *successful* POST request, you normally make a *redirect*, to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: I see what you mean. The reason I changed this was because when I switched to function based views, if I redirected then I could not use our modals, which the only way I could call was if I could render a variable, that if it was not None, it meant the modal would get triggered, but when not redirecting, I couldn’t get the form to “clear” upon submission, which is why i added the “new” form. Is there an easy way around cleaning out the form upon a successful submission?

Comment: @Mariana: then you can construct a new form in case of a succesful POST (so add `form = WarehouseForm()` at the end of the `if form.is_valid()` body.